# Running standard deviation on multiindexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to compute a running standard deviation (SD) on a multiindexed dataframe like this?

```
                    Value   SD
Symbol  Date        
ABC     19APR2017   35.43   0.00
        20APR2017   28.41   4.96
        21APR2017   33.8    3.67
DEF     19APR2017   10      0.00
        20APR2017   15      3.54
        21APR2017   12      2.52
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try of grouping the df with the index level 0 and use `pd.rolling` calculate standard deviation with specified length of rolling window

```
df.groupby(df.index.get_level_levels(0))['Value'].rolling(2).std()
```

**or**

from @ayhan inputs

```
df.groupby(level='Symbol')['Value'].rolling(2).std()
```

**Edit**

to calculate cummulative standard deviation of column

```
df = df.assign(std=df['Value'].apply(lambda x:[x])).groupby(level='Symbol').apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())
df['std'] = df['std'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).std())
```

**or**

```
df.groupby(df.index.get_level_levels(0))['Value'].transform(lambda x: [x[:i+1].std() for i in range(len(x))])
```

Out:

```
a         NaN
b    4.963890
c    3.673994
d         NaN
e    3.535534
f    2.516611
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The dataset was a sample with many more `Date` rows. How can it the rolling(2) be made dynamic?

Comment: it will work fine even it have many date rows, pandas rollling window is vectorized solution of calculating std.  @reservoirinvest do you want to change the rolling window w.r.t date rows?

Comment: The rolling(2) seems to compute only for fixed window of 2 days. There are multiple and variable rows for each Symbol. e.g. ABC - 22APR2017. Any possibility to make this dynamic?

Comment: the expected output is showing importance of using rolling window 2 with each symbol,  please consider asking new question if your requirement is different to this.

Comment: @reservoirinvest i just added code for calculating std for each added value, please check